# Vb .Net Read Webpage Source (Not using StreamReader)

Tags: vb.net, iframe, web-scraping

I would like to read the (Any)webpage source(Not using StreamReader) even if the webpage loads inside iFrame.

Thanks & Regards,
Rajah

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the html that includes the iframe and find the different url that the iframe requests.